# Batch If Else Statement Closes Window

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I have setup a custom batch file to install a game server. But the issue is that it closes when you would supply a response. It use multiple IF statements.

```
set /P input6=Would you like a custom loadout (Y/N):
if %input6%==Y (
echo ---------------------------
echo Default
echo Survival
echo PvP
echo ---------------------------
set /P input7=Which one:
if %input7%==Default (
perl db_utility.pl [] ["DZ_Patrol_Pack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]]
goto package
)
if %input7%==Survival (
perl db_utility.pl [["ItemMap","ItemCompass","ItemMatchbox","FoodCanBakedBeans","ItemKnife","FoodCanBakedBeans"],["ItemTent","ItemBandage","ItemBandage"]] ["DZ_Patrol_Pack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]] 
goto package
)
if %input7%==PvP (
perl db_utility.pl [["Mk_48_DZ","NVGoggles","Binocular_Vector","M9SD","ItemGPS","ItemToolbox","ItemCompass","FoodCanBakedBeans","ItemMap","ItemWatch"],[["100Rnd_762x51_M240",47],"ItemPainkiller","ItemBandage","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","100Rnd_762x51_M240","ItemBandage","ItemBandage","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","ItemMorphine"]] ["DZ_Backpack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]]
goto package
)
)
```

Comment: Run `help set` on the command line and read the part about delayed variable expansion.  What's happening now is your variables inside the "if" are being expanded to empty strings, which is causing a syntax error, which causes your batch file to terminate.

Comment: @indiv So that means just putting quotes around the input7 variable should suffice. I'm mobile today, so can't check, but I'd love to know.

Comment: @Mogsdad:  Not just quotes.  You need to `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of the script, and then instead of `%input7%`, you'd do `!input7!`.  The `!` means to wait until runtime to expand the variable (whereas the `%` confusingly means to expand the variable at **parse** time).  If you set a value inside a block (like an `if` or `for`), and you also want to use this value inside the same block, you must use delayed expansion.  If you use the variable outside the block, then you can use regular expansion.

Comment: @indiv Thanks, I'll play with that. Always nice to learn something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran your batch file, I got this error:

```
( was unexpected at this time.
```

When I reduced the number of lines of script between the open and close parentheses, the script would work. So I think you need to restructure the batch file, and avoid the nested `if` structure. Try something like this:

```
set /P input6=Would you like a custom loadout (Y/N): 
echo input6 is %input6%
if not "%input6%"=="Y" goto done

  echo input6 is %input6%

  echo ---------------------------
  echo Default
  echo Survival
  echo PvP
  echo ---------------------------
  set /P input7=Which one:
  if %input7%==Default (
    perl db_utility.pl [] ["DZ_Patrol_Pack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]]
    goto package
  )
  if %input7%==Survival (
  perl db_utility.pl [["ItemMap","ItemCompass","ItemMatchbox","FoodCanBakedBeans","ItemKnife","FoodCanBakedBeans"],["ItemTent","ItemBandage","ItemBandage"]] ["DZ_Patrol_Pack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]] 
  goto package
  )
  if %input7%==PvP (
    perl db_utility.pl [["Mk_48_DZ","NVGoggles","Binocular_Vector","M9SD","ItemGPS","ItemToolbox","ItemCompass","FoodCanBakedBeans","ItemMap","ItemWatch"],[["100Rnd_762x51_M240",47],"ItemPainkiller","ItemBandage","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","100Rnd_762x51_M240","ItemBandage","ItemBandage","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","15Rnd_9x19_M9SD","ItemMorphine"]] ["DZ_Backpack_EP1",[[],[]],[[],[]]]
    goto package
  )
:done
```